# Building confidence intervals for yearly currency depreciation using daily data

Tags: confidence-interval, econometrics

I have daily USD/GBP exchange rates (for the past 5 years), from which i can calculate daily depreciation rates. From this I know how to build confidence intervals for daily depreciation rates.

Is there a way to use this data to build confidence intervals for yearly depreciation rates?

One way I thought of was to calculate yearly depreciation rates by using exchange rates a year apart, and use a data set of these yearly rates to build confidence intervals.